# Error de ejecución android-studio "compileDebugwithJavac"

Tags: android, android-studio

Aunque la sincronización del Gradle se completa exitosamente, al intentar lanzar la aplicación se muestra el siguiente mensaje:

```
"Execution failed for task: 'app:compileDebugwithJavac' > compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

He intentado lo que se me sugería en la consola de Gradle pero ello no ha solucionado el problema, y no encuentro dónde ver "compiler error output", ya que por lo que he visto en otras preguntas del foro estaría en File>settings>compiler, pero no tengo una opción para ello.

buil.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aplic.x"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Error mostrado en consola:

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

He probado las tres opciones que se ofrecen y el resultado ha sido el mismo.

Por esto, me gustaría saber cómo solucionar este problema.

Comment: Agrega tu build.gradle y revisa que error te muestra  en la consola, este error es debido a multiples causas por lo tanto tienes que especificar.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente asegura [instalar la versión del SDK 26](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html?hl=es-419) desde el sdk manager

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si al actualizar, no se resuelve el error, este error podría ser similar al que surgio cuando fue liberada la versión buildtools 24, al actualizar a la [última versión](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html), como opción podría ser cambiar a la versión 25.